# Does sending an email through aws require only AccessKey and SecretKey?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

im using this dependency https://github.com/daniel-zahariev/php-aws-ses to send email through AWS and i don't see where can I set host, username, ports and password. is there a way to set it does anyone know how to usethis php-aws-ses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you specify `accessKey` and `secretKey` [here](https://github.com/daniel-zahariev/php-aws-ses/blob/master/src/SimpleEmailService.php#L135):

```
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param string $accessKey Access key
     * @param string $secretKey Secret key
     * @param string $host Amazon Host through which to send the emails
     * @param boolean $trigger_errors Trigger PHP errors when AWS SES API returns an error
     * @param string $requestSignatureVersion Version of the request signature
     *               Currently only V4 supported by AWS. Keeping parameter for BW compatibility reasons.
     */
    public function __construct($accessKey = null, $secretKey = null, $host = self::AWS_US_EAST_1, $trigger_errors = true, $requestSignatureVersion = self::REQUEST_SIGNATURE_V4) {
        if ($accessKey !== null && $secretKey !== null) {
            $this->setAuth($accessKey, $secretKey);
        }
        $this->__host = $host;
        $this->__trigger_errors = $trigger_errors;
        $this->__requestSignatureVersion = $requestSignatureVersion;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The software probably connect to Amazon SES via the PHP SDK rather than treating it as an SMTP server. Therefore, only AWS credentials are required.

However, Amazon SES starts in a "sandbox" mode. You can only send emails to verified addresses. You will need to request to [Move out of the Amazon SES sandbox - Amazon Simple Email Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/request-production-access.html) when sending to "outside" recipients.